# Transfer a BitmapData object from an AS2 swf to a parent AS3 swf via SWFBridge

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I need to transfer a BitmapData object created in an AS2 swf to an AS3 swf. I'm using gskinner's [SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html)  to establish a two way communication between both flash movies.

The AS3 movie loads the AS2 swf which works completely standalone and lets the user manipulate MovieClips and finally generate an image from the composition he creates. I need the AS3 movie to receive this image (bitmapData), do some fancy image processing stuff AS2 isn't able to do and send the new image back to the AS2 movie.

So here's the code

**AS2 swf:**

```
var userCompo_mc:MovieClip = container.createEmptyMovieClip("userCompo_mc",10);
var image:BitmapData = new BitmapData(userCompo_mc._width, userCompo_mc._height);
finalCompo.attachBitmap(image); // Just to make sure the final bitmap is right
image.draw(userCompo_mc, compo.title);

//Send the image to the AS3 movie
sb1.send("imageTransfer",image);
```

**AS3 swf:**

```
function imageTransfer(bitmapData:BitmapData, title:String):void
{
    var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    this.addChild(bmp);
    trace(title); // --> returns the right title
    trace(bitmapData); // --> returns null
}
```

I think using something like copyPixel32(), saving everything into an array and then passing it to AS3 would do the trick but it's really a performance hog.

Also, I'm not *allowed* to convert the AS2 swf into AS3 code.

Any suggestions?

Thanks you!

Comment: how about looping through the pixels in as2, filling a single array with uints and check if you can send those through. If that works, you can then cast that Array to Vector.<uint> in as3 and colour your bitmap data using setVector(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#setVector())

Comment: I think it could work, but looping through pixels in as2 using getPixel32() takes about 3 to 4 seconds. I think it's too much time, I need something faster because users need to see the result as fast as possible to proceed with other tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the as2 movie adds some decorations/movieclips to a an image. 
After that you draw it and send attempt to send it to as3.

Since looping though all the pixels is slow, as you mention, I imagine it's faster to draw the as2 content from the as3 movie.

e.g.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest('yourAS2Movie.swf'),new LoaderContext(true));

function loaded(event:Event):void{
    var as2Clip:AVM1Movie = AVM1Movie(loader.content);
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(as2Clip.width,as2Clip.height,false,0);
    bd.draw(as2Clip);
    addChild(new Bitmap(bd));
}
```

In this snippet the as2 content is drawn on load. In your case you would trigger/call a function that draws the as2 content via SWFBridge, after the as2 movie is ready/setup for what you need.

This works assuming you want to display the as2 content inside the as3 movie, which means you will load the as2 movie anyway. If not, either you load the as2 content, but don't add it to the display list, which means you'll be loading the as2 movie. Otherwise, you could try to save your final bitmap from the as2 movie using a server side language(like php for example), then trigger a function in the as3 movie, via SWFBridge, that will load the previously saved image.

HTH

Comment: Yes! I think this could be the solution. I'll try it. Thanks a lot!